# Include WebService app.config settings in code

Tags: c#, web-services, ssis

my code includes a reference to a webservice, if I want it to run, I need the following section in my app.config:

```
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://123.45.6.78:8080/ASPPO/StartASPPOCallBack"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="StartASPPOCallBackPortBinding"
            contract="ASPPOCallBack.StartASPPOCallBack" name="StartASPPOCallBackPort" />
    </client>
```

My problem is now, that my code gets called by a SSIS-package and this doesn't have any app.config. So I somehow need to include all the settings I need directy in the code, because I will get a System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException otherwise.

But I actually have no idea where to put it. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Does SSIS invoke your code as an external app or an SSIS component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your code is invoked by SSIS (not via external app) you have to modyfy `.config` file of application which will execute your SSIS package: `DTExec.exe`, `dtshost.exe`, `devenv.exe`, `DTExecUI.exe`. Here you have more info of appropriate .config locactions: http://www.sqlis.com/post/Where-is-my-appconfig-for-SSIS.aspx

Alternatively you can configure your endpoint in code (not via `.config` file) similar to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2010/07/08/how-to-configure-an-ssis-package-to-access-a-web-service-using-wcf.aspx

Comment: I had this issue just yesterday with ASP.NET. I had to add the app.config-settings for my service into my web.config. I'm sure Piotr's notes are good.

Comment: Thanks, the 2nd approach was what I needed.